# I can't snap 2d cursor to vertex in UV editor in blender 2.8

Tags: uv-image-editor

I'm in UV Editor and trying to snap the 2d cursor to the vertex ( while the vertices are visible). I turn ON snap and set it to 'vertex mode' , but the 2d cursor won't snap to any visible vertex at all. I can only make it snap to the grid (increment node). Is it a bug ? or did i miss something here ? i'm using 2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turn on snapping in *UV Editor* and the only thing that snaps is the vertex that I move, snapping to the location of the nearest vertex. I don't believe that snapping works with the cursor location, that I still have to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  menu and choose *Too Selection*.